# Apache Camel Multiple line file parsing fails

Tags: java, file, apache-camel

I am trying to convert fixed length file but it fails for multiple file and works for single line.

```
        public class SampleCamelRouter extends RouteBuilder {
            Processor processor = new FixedMapProcessor();
            DataFormat bindy = new BindyFixedLengthDataFormat(Order.class);

            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {

                from("file:C:/Users/in").unmarshal(bindy)
                        .split(body()).process(new Processor() {
                            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        //Below is not working
        List<Map<String, Object>> unmarshaledModels = (List<Map<String, Object>>) exchange.getIn().getBody();

        //Below is working
            Order2 unmarshaledModels = (Order2) exchange.getIn().getBody();
                            }
                        }).end();
            }    
        }
```

**Order:**

```
@FixedLengthRecord(length = 4, paddingChar = ' ')
public class Order1 {

    @DataField(pos = 1, length = 2)
    private int orderNr;

    @DataField(pos = 3, length = 2)
    private String clientNr;
}
```

**C:/Users/in/test.txt**

```
10AB
20CD
```

**Exception:**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.camel.fixed1.Order cannot be cast to java.util.List
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple line of file is also getting processed properly but it is not coming as a list.Instead processor is executing for each line of the input file.

new Processor() {} -- is getting executed, so below line will be executed for each record.

```
Order2 unmarshaledModels = (Order2) exchange.getIn().getBody();
```